# passing arrays to functions in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, memory-management

I want to pass an array to a certain function in c++. I wrote the following code:

```
#define nmpart 50

void distances( double (&dis)[3][nmpart][nmpart] )
{
    ... compute distances which are allocated in "dis"
}

double energy()
{
        double dis[3][nmpart][nmpart];

        distances(dis);
}
```

This code is working fine when nmpart<800 approximately. The issue is that I would like
to have a bigger array let say for nmpart=50000. I have read in this forum that one 
can use dynamical allocation to overcome this problem. It is not clear for me how could
I use dynamical allocation in this situation. Could you give me some hints.

Comment: Are you sure you need an array that big? When nmpart=50000 you'll have 50000*50000*3*sizeof(double), which would be 60 GB. Using dynamic allocation will only make things a lot worse, since it'll require extra space for control structures. If the array is only partially populated, a sparse array would be better. If not, maybe your algorithm could be changed to calculate the distances on-demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, a lot of people (including myself) would never write this code professionally (or otherwise) but it basically answers your question.  See below for why I'd never write this professionally.

```
#define nmpart 50  

void distances( const double ***dist) 
{     
    ... compute distances which are allocated in "dis" 
}  

double energy()
{ 
     double ***dis;

     // allocate dis
     dis = new double**[3];
     for(int i=0;i<3;++i)
     {
         dis[i] = new double*[nmpart];
         for(int j=0;j<nmpart;++j)
         {
              dis[i][j] = new double[nmpart];
         }
     }

     // code where you populate dis
     // HERE

     distances(dis);

     // deallocate dis
     for(int i=0;i<3;++i)
     {
         for(int j=0;j<nmpart;++j)
         {
              delete [] dis[i][j];
         }
         delete [] dis[i];
     }
     delete [] dis;

}
```

Basically, I'd never write this (other than for instructional purposes) because if there's an exception thrown somewhere in this function, then it's going to leak memory.  The best thing to do would be to wrap the heap allocations and deallocations (with `new` and `delete` respectively) in a class and put that class on the local stack inside your `energy()` function.

Ideally you'd do something like this:

```
#define nmpart 50    

void distances( const distClass &dis)  
{          
   ... compute distances which are allocated in "dis"  
}

double energy() 
{  
    distClass dis;
    // this allocate wraps the for loops with the new []'s above
    dis.Allocate(3, nmpart , nmpart);  

    // populate dis HERE

    distances(dis);

    // when dis goes out of scope its destructor
    // is called, which wraps the for loops with the delete []'s
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use std::vector instead. This allow dynamic allocation.

```
void distances( std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<double> > > const& dis )
{
    ... compute distances which are allocated in "dis"
}

double energy()
{
    std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<double> > > dis;

    distances(dis);
}
```

Comment: how could I set up the size of the array [3][nmpart][nmpart] using the std::vector?

Comment: Hm... while this is technically the dynamic version of the OP's question, I'd say any solution that involves a vector of vectors of vectors is a bit broken :-) How about a single array or vector accessed in strides?

Comment: you can use dis.resize(3) for the first element, then a loop over the second part with  for (i=0;i<dis.size();i++){dis[i].resize(nmpart);} and then a last loop for the last for (i=0;i<dis.size();i++){for (j=0;j<dis[i].size();j++)dis[i][j].resize(nmpart);}. This looks horrible. Therefor the suggestion of Kerrek SB to use one array which saves the data   consecutively  might be better. How can one make code in comments?

Comment: @Kerrek SB, I'm not arguing, but why do you consider any solution that involves a vector of vectors broken?

Comment: @ChrisA.: It's just way too involved. Having that much allocation going on can't be healthy. A flat vector accessed in strides gives you far better memory locality and fewer allocations.

Comment: With big dimensions a single vector could be worse. Inserting/adding elements would be costly, to grow the array it'll  need one big allocation, and the copy of the elements afterwards. You'll also need more than double the array size of total available memory (for temporarily in reallocations there will be the old and new coexisting).

Comment: @FabioCeconello: Yes, that's a good point. It all depends on the usage profile. If you want to resize a lot (which the OP's code didn't lead me to believe) you may be better of with nested structures. On the other hand, if you loop a lot through a fixed sized structure, the single array might let you benefit from memory locality (provided you stride it the right way round). Nothing beats profiling and comparing, eh? :-)